# Variable retrieved by hook is not updated in components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook that handle login client side by storing in localstorage user infos.
Everything woks fine except that the user retrieved by this hook in my components is not updated after the use of login method

```
const useAuth = () => {

    const localStorageUserKey = "@mysite:user"

    const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const userJson = window.localStorage.getItem(localStorageUserKey);

        if (userJson) {
            setUser(JSON.parse(userJson));
        }
    }, []);

    const login = (newUser: IUser) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageUserKey, JSON.stringify(newUser));
        setUser(newUser);
    }

    const logout = () => {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(localStorageUserKey);
        setUser(null);
        navigate("/");
    }

    return { login, logout, user }
}

export default useAuth;
```

I used it like that

```
export default function LoginPage() {
    const { post } = useApi();
    const { login } = useAuth();
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const onSubmit = (email: string, password: string) => {

        setError("");

        post<ILoginApiResponse>("/login", { email, password }).then((r) => {
            if (r.data.user) {
                login(r.data.user);
            }
        }).catch((r) => {
            if (r.response.status === 400) {
                setError("Identifiants invalides");
            } else {
                setError("Une erreur est survenue");
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Connexion</h2>
            {error ? <ErrorMessage message={error} /> : null}
            <LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And an example of using user

```
export default function Layout(props: ILayoutProps) {

    const { user, logout } = useAuth();

    return <div className={"main-container"}>
        <header className="header-container">
            <nav>
                <ul className={"header-nav"}>
                    /* ... */
                    {!user ? 
                        <li className={"item"}>
                          <a className={"header-nav-link"} href="/login">Connexion</a>
                        </li> : 
                        <li>
                        <button className={"header-nav-link"} onClick={logout}>Se déconnecter</button>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <Outlet />
    </div>;

}
```

User is set in localstorage and is updated in hook (tried with a useEffect) but not in components retrieving it.

Any ideas why ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks are encapsulated and isolated units of logic that can be called from various components. The data stored in the state of `useAuth` called from `LoginPage` is different from that called in `Layout`. Think what would happen if you were to take the logic from inside the hook, and just place it in both components separately.

Custom hooks are for encapsulating reusable logic, not state. To encapsulate reusable state, you can use the [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) built into React. Then, a custom hook could provide access to that context, but that's not necessary.

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext<ContextState>(defaultContextValues);

export function ContextProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);

  const login = () => { ... };

  const logout = () => { ... };

  return <AuthContext.Ptovider values={{ 
    user,
    login,
    logout,
   }}
  >
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
};

export function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AughContext);
};
```

Now your entire state is kept in one place, and all components in `children` can use it by calling `useAuth`. Remember to wrap you app with `AuthProvider`.

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      {/* components go here */}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Didn't know that hooks where not meant to handle logic only.

Comment: You can have hooks handle anything, just remember that they are just functions. Every time you call a hook from a new place, a duplicate call is created, hence the duplicated state.